# Big model table view solution Swift

Tags: ios, swift, model, swift4

I have a question about what in your opinion is the best way to handle my problem.

The case is, I have models that are really big and contain lots of data. These are stored in a database and sent to the client. Now I would like to show this data in way of table views. Showing the data is not the problem but the best way to access it is.

**My question is: What is a smart way to handle big data models in table view cells**

So to give an example I have model that contains say 30 variables.
Now I have a page view controller with a table view in there where on the first page I would like to show variable 1,2,5,6,7,9,10 and the next page 1,2,21,23,24,22 (of 100 objects) and above the page there is a little indicator what the number or string means.

So I thought of a solution with Swift 4

```
typealias listTypeObject = (name: String, minSize: Int, object: KeyPath<Any, Any>)
```

A problem here is that you can not convert key path types so it can not accept my key paths. So this will not work not in this state at least. If someone knows a solution for this that would be amazing!

The other solution would be creating every list by hand with the header and content separate. This will cost me a lot of lines of code that I would imagine could be much smaller.

I hope someone can show me a better way or just tell me that the best way is by hand.

Thanks a lot!

**Update 1:** 
code example// This is the list with the pages

```
enum listTypes {
    case player
    case playerPoints
    case team
}

// I have a base model
class BaseModel {

    var id: Int = 0
    let updated: Date = Date()

    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
}

// I have multiple final models like this but bigger
final class PlayerModel: BaseModel {
    var firstName: String = "John"
    var surname: String = "Doe"

    var pointsInFootball: Int = 60
    var pointsInBasketball: Int = 23

    init(id: Int, firstName: String, surname: String, pointsInFootball: Int, pointsInBasketball: Int) {
        super.init(id: id)

        self.firstName = firstName
        self.surname = surname

        self.pointsInFootball = pointsInFootball
        self.pointsInBasketball = pointsInBasketball
    }
}

final class TeamModel: BaseModel {
    var name: String = "TeamTest"
}

// Lets create the example
var dataArray: [BaseModel] = []

// Add some test objects to the array
for i in 0..<10 {
    let object = PlayerModel(id: i, firstName: "John\(i)", surname: "Doe\(i)", pointsInFootball: 10 * i, pointsInBasketball: 5 * i)
    dataArray.append(object)
}

// So now in the list I would like to say what is accessible for the table view
// listTypes.player = PlayerModel: firstName - surname - age
// listTypes.playerPoints = PlayerModel: firstName - pointsInFootball - pointsInBasketball - pointsInSkiing
// But list type team should be
// listTypes.team = TeamModel: name
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, I think you should use enums. By using an array of enums, it can isolate the variables you want to present, and you won't have to create unique tableViews in order to accomplish this. You just pass an array to the tableView delegate/datasouce functions. Without a code example / further information, this is all I can deduce.

Comment: I've added an example made in playgrounds, hope it makes it a little clearer what I want to accomplish. If you miss something let me know.

Comment: @JippeJoosten So from what I understand you want the table view to only present certain data of each player object? So like if you wanted to only present all basketball points vs all points in football? & soccer?

Comment: Exactly, this is the goal and find the most efficient way.

Comment: Well what you can do is what I wrote above, use an array of enums to dictate what is presented; pass this in to the cell during the cell instantiation of the "cellForItemAt". So in the cell, you can decide what is presented by the passed in enum array.

Comment: Could you give me a example, I heard about this before but on a project like mine where you have a couple really big models the enum will be really big and don't understand how the enum access the value

Comment: @JippeJoosten so what you would want to do is, if there are pre-defined sets of attributes that you want to present, then you can preload the array with enums. Then you pass this array into the cell when you create the cell and inside the code for the UITableViewCell, you have a switch statement that dictates what is presented on the cell. So let's say the cell has 3 labels, when the array is passed in to the cell, the switch statement can determine which label presents what data.